# AutoHotKey: How to click right mouse on selected SysListView and select item from menu

Tags: autohotkey

How can I click the right mouse button on a selected list item? (See image: 2nd item with blue background). The mouse position might be somewhere else so I have to identify which item is selected and where it is. And then in the next step I want to press the left mouse button on an item in the menu that opens. Environment: Windows 7.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for the [Menu Key/ AppsKey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)!

Add this piece of code after you have highlighted your box with the AHK script (i.e. where you would otherwise put your right-click)

```
Send {Appskey}
```

Comment: I have used this code to test AppsKey:
F4:: 
Send {Appskey} 
Return 

It only works on other fields in this application. If I click in a field of the ClassNN = Edit10 and press F4, the right mouse context menu appears. But in the ClassNN SysListView322 it doesn't work. Nothing happens. Any other ideas?

Comment: The only other thing I can really think of would be to run a pixel search to try to find a pixel that matched the color that a highlighted cell is, and then click on that pixel. For obvious reasons, this can be extremely unreliable, especially if that color also occurs on other parts of the screen. Still, it might be worth trying that if there are no better ideas.